# Logo in Dropdown Menu not Inline with Links

Tags: html, user-interface, drop-down-menu, css

I have tried asking this question for 3 days, in various formats. I can't seem to isolate the problem.

I have a dropdown menu that uses a hidden checkbox.

I have attached my logo to the bottom of that menu.

When triggered, the menu rolls down. The logo rolls down with it.

**The problem is that the logo is on another line, below the menu links, and as such the menu drops down too low, conflicting with the title.**

**I would like the logo to roll down with the menu, but display the links on the same line, thus reducing the height of the open menu by the height of the logo**

I tried `inline-block`, `inline`, and a million other tweaks, to no avail.

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shivashivashiva/cdh8tnvf/2/[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/k0aky3de/)

Add an inner div to menu, so that everyting absolute can be relative to that.

It takes #logo out of the ul like:

```
<span id="logo"></span>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">how it works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

then make the logo:
    postion:absolute;
    bottom: 0;

To keep it just above the line.

Comment: Not quite. I **want** the header to collapse, and I want the links to be visible. Thanks for you response

Comment: So the header should get bigger when the links appear? If so, should the logo drop below the horizontal line?

Comment: Yes the header should drop below the links, giving the impression that the line is "revealing" them. Meanwhile, the logo should stick to the line. @bobdye

Comment: Before you do, could you please make sure that the "myapp" company name is visible ? Thanks other than that it looks good

Comment: Yes. It's a matter of adjusting the height of menu-inner to what you want.

Comment: hey for some reason it stopped working? the line is no longer moving @bobdye

Comment: If you mean the Fiddle, it is because it doesn't need to. If you want to see it move, add some margin-bottom to .menu ul.

Answer (score 1):

See this [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdh8tnvf/4/)

I changed the `position:absolute` to `relative` on the `.menu` definition (the second definition).

```
.menu {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't mean to imply that I'm trying to implement this feature at the expense of the current design, such as having the content pushed with the dropdown.

Comment: Also, this doesn't solve the problem. The logo and the links are still not inline. @Ted

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now, let me take a poke at it

Comment: any luck at all? @Ted

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following to put the logo and text on the same line:

```
menu ul {
    float: right;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}
```

Also in my firefox version 35.0.1 the text is not entirely visible because of the use of

```
.menu ul{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and the max-height you've used for menu. You should also make some adjustments there.
If you also want to adjust the text line height in order to center the text vertically with the image you can adjust the padding for .menu li

Comment: That doesn't work the menu doesn't drop down. Thanks for your response.

Comment: See this. http://jsfiddle.net/cdh8tnvf/14/. Add float:right just for .menu ul and it works.

Comment: No, it does not work. It does not follow the specified requirements.